# Segmentation Fault with pointer arithmetics C++

Tags: c++, pointers, g++, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to learn some manupulations of pointer arithmetics in C++. The code written below throws me a Segmentation Fault.  I could not comprehend how the program tries to access unallocated memory to cause a segmentation fault.

**C++ Code** (*myarray.cc*)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int * pointer_s3_1_a;
  int * pointer_s3_1_a2;
  int value_s3_1_a, value_s3_1_a2 ;

  *pointer_s3_1_a=100;
  cout<<"pointer_s3_1_a, *pointer_s3_1_a "<<pointer_s3_1_a<<' '<<*pointer_s3_1_a<<endl;
  value_s3_1_a=*pointer_s3_1_a++; 
  cout<<"value_s3_1_a, pointer_s3_1_a, *pointer_s3_1_a "<<
    value_s3_1_a<<' '<<pointer_s3_1_a<<' '<<*pointer_s3_1_a<<endl;

  cout<<"pointer_s3_1_a2, *pointer_s3_1_a2 "<<pointer_s3_1_a2<<' '<<*pointer_s3_1_a2<<endl;

  *pointer_s3_1_a2=100; //Runtime error |** Segmentation fault (core dumped) **|

  return 0;
}
```

I'm running the program in Ubuntu 12.04 with g++ compiler. Running *apt-cache policy g++* on terminal gave me the following output.

> g++:   Installed: 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5   Candidate: 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5
>   Version table:  *** 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 0
>           500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
>           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: `int * pointer_s3_1_a;` ... `*pointer_s3_1_a=100;` is UB. Please **PLEASE** learn C++ using a book. Don't throw code in and expect it to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here, you declare a pointer that points to nowhere in particular:

```
int * pointer_s3_1_a;
```

Here, you attempt to set the value of the thing it points to to `100`:

```
*pointer_s3_1_a=100;
```

This is *undefined behaviour*, and could cause a segmentation violation (although it doesn't have to, many wrong things could happen, and not all as noticeable as a segmentation fault. You just got lucky).

You must first make your pointer point to somewhere valid. For example,

```
int n = 42;
pointer_s3_1_a = &n; // pointer points to n
*pointer_s3_1_a=100; // set the value of the thing it points to (n) to 100
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write data to uninitialized areas of memory:

```
int * pointer_s3_1_a;  // NOT Initialized (possibly 0)!!!
*pointer_s3_1_a=100;   // Undefined behaviour
```

Comment: It's very unlikely to be `0`, actually. And a page fault is only one possible outcome.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OK, fixed comments.

Answer (score 2):

you have declared 
pointer_s3_1_a and
pointer_s3_1_a2 as pointers, but there's actually no memory to point to, as you have missed to allocate/create them.
You should do:

```
int* pointer_s3_1_a = new int();
*pointer_s3_1_a = 100;
```

...

```
int* pointer_s3_1_a2 = new int();
*pointer_s3_1_a2 = 100;
```